# react native: multiple command produce same file. XCode error

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Getting following erorr in ios project, inside react native app.

Showing All Errors Only

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapps-cebtqkqvjkhixpaaqvrgdmyzymyv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-test/react_native_test.framework/Headers/test.h':

1) Target 'react-native-test' (project 'Pods') has copy command from 
'/Users/admin/Desktop/Baajar/myapp/ios/Pods/react-native-test/ios/test.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/test.framework/Headers/test.h' 
to
 '/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapps-cebtqkqvjkhixpaaqvrgdmyzymyv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-test/react_native_test.framework/Headers/test.h'

2) Target 'react-native-test' (project 'Pods') has copy command from
 '/Users/admin/Desktop/Baajar/myapp/ios/Pods/react-native-test/ios/test.xcframework/ios-arm64_i386_x86_64-simulator/test.framework/Headers/test.h' 
to 
'/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapps-cebtqkqvjkhixpaaqvrgdmyzymyv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/react-native-test/react_native_test.framework/Headers/test.h'
```

i am using **react: "16.13.1", XCode: 13.12.1**

i tried pod deintegrate pod reinstall, pod cache clean, but nothing worked.
i searched solutions online someone says try to use old lagacy build system, but xcode doesn't allow it, it throws error.

i can not update react or xcode versions for some other depedency reasons.

attaching duplicate header files for reference. if i remove 1 copy out of 2 copy then it will throw 50+ errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: converting to lagacy build system, throws many errors related to framework. around 50+ errors.

Comment: what i understood is simulator based framework and device based framework both are trying to copy file at same location, resulting in multiple copy.

Comment: It looks like in a similar error [here](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/1074) that you can just remove the files, so that they are only the Pods Resources.

Comment: no this one is different, xcframework has two parts one is simulator based another is device based, both framework are trying to copy resources at same location.